# Should this answer be flagged as spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27539697/1679537), next to [this deleted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27494322/1679537). It appears clearly from [the author's GitHub](https://github.com/abdennour/spl/tree/master/spl/JS-ORMQuery) that he also wrote the mentioned library.

Should this question be flagged as spam ? I mean, the post answers the question (or at least tries to), but it's also clearly promoting this library without any kind of disclosure.

On the other hand, the user is clearly a regular one, usually posting valid questions/answers.

I'm also wondering because one of both answers already got deleted, for an unknown reason, so I don't want to push further if the matter has already be discussed and dealt with.

This looks like spam-by-mistake to me. Maybe just ask him to add a disclosure ?

I lack experience in spam handling, except for obvious ones, so any advice is welcome.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert either on this, but if the guy is active, comment and ask him? He might just not know about disclosure. Is he trying to shove his product down everyone's throat or is it legitimately something that would help here?

Comment: That was my first intention. But seeing a duplicate answer deleted, I ended up wondering if something already had been done about that. But you're right, I added a comment. Thanks

Comment: I should note that there was a conversation with a moderator at the time that was posted, and I think they refrained from posting that library again after that. I think they're aware of the issue and maybe just haven't taken the time to go back and edit that answer. For older posts like that, it can be helpful to check and see if they continued to post undisclosed links to personal projects or if they stopped.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks a lot, that's exactly the information I was hoping to get :) I kind of checked while writing this question, it seems that he didn't. I leave it at that then.